# linear gradient not working with margin/padding 0 and div #todo

Tags: css

I have a linear gradient background, but it only works if I remove from body:

```
 margin:0; 
 padding:0;
```

or if I remove the div #todo or rename it.

What is wrong?

```
body {

 margin:0; 
 padding:0;

background:
    linear-gradient(
        limegreen,
        transparent
    ),
    linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        skyblue,
        transparent
    ),
    linear-gradient(
        -90deg,
        coral,
        transparent
    );

background-blend-mode: screen !important;
}

#todo{
 position:absolute;
 top: 45%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align:center;
}
```

html

```
<div id="todo">linear gradient not working... only works if I remove margin and padding in body or remove this div #todo</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lo2fzha4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a height set.

Add this to your css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That happens, because your #todo div is set to position: absolute. You can imagine it as if it is "hovering" above your body without increasing its height or width.

As said before, you need to give your html and body a height.